# Sharepoint SPFile.Convert Infopath to HTML

Tags: 2007, development, infopath

i have the conversion code for converting from infopath to HTML

```
Guid id;
var conversionResults = newItem.Convert(new Guid("853d58f5-13c3-46f8-8b81-3ca4abcad7b3"), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(newItem.Name), null, "Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c", "Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.DocumentConversion", 1, String.Empty, false, true, out id);
```

Which i got from using the msdn convert http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.convert.aspx and general documentation around the subject but whenever i try to run it i get the exception

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.DocumentConversion' from assembly 'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.
   at System.Reflection.Assembly._GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDocumentTransformDriver.GetTransformProcessor(ExecutingTransformRequest etr)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDocumentTransformDriver.Transform(SPWebApplication wa, ExecutingTransformRequest etr)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.Convert(Guid ConverterId, String newFileName, String configInfo, String handlerAssembly, String handlerClass, Byte priority, String peopleToAlert, Boolean sendACopy, Boolean synchronous, Guid& workItemId)
   at RMS.FormServices.ConvertInfopathToASPX(String infopathFile, String fileNamingbasedon) in C:\Documents and Settings\UN\Source Control\Project\FormServices.asmx.cs:line 243
```

If i change it to

```
Guid id;
var conversionResults = newItem.Convert(new Guid("853d58f5-13c3-46f8-8b81-3ca4abcad7b3"), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(newItem.Name), null, "Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c", "Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.DocumentConversion", 1, String.Empty, false, false, out id);
```

it returns success however if i then try

```
var converted = newItem.GetConvertedFile(id);
```

it throws a exception and if i try

```
while (true)
{
    var state = newItem.GetConversionState(new Guid("853d58f5-13c3-46f8-8b81-3ca4abcad7b3"), id);
    if (state == SPFileConversionState.Completed)
        break;
}
```

then state hits pending, then after a while available state and never changes after that, ive been trying to get this code working for ages and any help would be appreciated

just as a side note, the convert Infopath to HTML is enabled on the sharepoint server, its all configured and it works from sharepoint (very slowly though) i just cant get it working from the code.

**Edit:** Some futher information after looking at the logs and with the conversion code looking like

```
var conversionResults = newItem.Convert(new Guid("853d58f5-13c3-46f8-8b81-3ca4abcad7b3"), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(newItem.Name), null, null, null, 1, String.Empty, false, true, out id);
```

the conversion fails and the following shows up in the logs

> 08/02/2011 14:53:42.83 Microsoft.Office.Server.Convers (0x04FC) 0x06BC Document Conversions Launcher Service 7jg8 Verbose Calling LoadBalancer.RegisterLauncher
>   08/02/2011 14:53:42.86 Microsoft.Office.Server.Convers (0x0538) 0x0CBC
>    Document Conversions  Load Balancer Service 7jhf Medium
>    RegisterLauncher called with uri http://SEED-DEV8:8082/HtmlTrLauncher
>   08/02/2011 14:53:42.86 Microsoft.Office.Server.Convers (0x0538) 0x0CBC Document Conversions Load Balancer Service 7jht Verbose LoadList: Add Called: http://SEED-DEV8:8082/HtmlTrLauncher, 0 
>   08/02/2011 14:53:42.86 Microsoft.Office.Server.Convers (0x0538) 0x0CBC Document Conversions Load Balancer Service 7jhu Verbose (note: expected after EnsureLoadBalancerStatus call) register launcher called for uri that's already registered: http://SEED-DEV8:8082/HtmlTrLauncher 
>   08/02/2011 14:53:42.88 Microsoft.Office.Server.Convers (0x04FC) 0x06BC Document Conversions Launcher Service 7jg9 Verbose LoadBalancer.RegisterLauncher succesful
>   08/02/2011 14:53:42.81 Microsoft.Office.Server.Convers (0x04FC) 0x06BC Document Conversions Launcher Service 7jdv Verbose EnsureLoadBalancerStatus called

**Edit 2:** i changed the max size for the converter and it is running a lot faster now from both code and sharepoint but the conversion code is still not working and just comming up as failure. the [Log](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21464539/Sharepoint%20Converter%20Logs.txt) for the converter can be found here (everything from the start of the convert code till the end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the root of the problem is your assembly reference is for the SP2007 Forms Server (i.e. **Version=12.0.0.0**).  I'm not sure there is even a 2010 equivalent, as the DocumentConversion class does not exist in Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server, **Version=14.0.0.0**

You could try not specifying the Assembly and Class (...they are optional and I think primarily used to specify a pre or post conversion handler)...the Conversion Launcher should be able to act on the GUID of the InfoPath Transformer (...which is correct).

So change the **Assembly** and **Class** references to **null** and see if that does the trick.

UPDATE: I set this up in one of my dev environments and it worked without the Assembly or Class arguments:

```
SPFileConversionResult result = file.Convert(new Guid("853d58f5-13c3-46f8-8b81-3ca4abcad7b3"), "test123", null, null, null, 1, String.Empty, false, true, out id);
```

One other to check is make sure you have enabled document conversion on your web app: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770243.aspx.  I suspect you have already done this because I don't think you'd be seeing the error, but putting it out there just in case.

Comment: thanks that fixed my original problem but unfortunately the conversionResult is failure, do you know how i can find out why it failed?

Comment: I'd look in the ULS log (Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS OOB). Should log the error(s) there.

Comment: it seems to have been spitting out wsstracing.exe (0x0A9C)                  0x0AD8 ULS Logging Unified Logging Service uls1 Monitorable Tracing Service lost trace events.  Current value 2. all through the conversion but no other items seem to have been logged

Comment: Go into "Central Admin > Monitoring > Configure diagnostic logging", check the "Document Conversions" category, select "Medium" or "Verbose" from the "Least critical event to report to the trace log" dropdown, and click OK.  Try the operation again.

Comment: Hi Rob, sorry to keep bothering you, ive updated the question with the logs of the converter but i cant work out whats going wrong, would you mind pointing me in the right direction, any help is appreciated

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing any errors in the log. Make sure document conversion is enabled in central admin for the site and click on the Customize "From InfoPath Form to Web Page" (xml into html) link under Converter Settings section and makme sure it's enabled (...checked).  Also go back to diagnostic loggin and set the Conversion and Deployment category under InfoPath Forms Services to Verbose...maybe that will give us an error.

Comment: Hi Rob, have changed the converter log to verbose and attached the logs for the document conversion and RiskManagementGenericConsoleApp (the console app I am running the convert code from) any enlightenment as to what is happening is appreciated

Comment: Are you by any chance running this in a single server environment where the SP server is also a domain controller? If not and you're running on Windows 2008 then make sure UAC is turned off.

Comment: i am running it in a single server environment on windows sever 2003 R2 (SP2) and as far as i am aware the server is also the domain controller (the console app is also being run from the server)

Comment: As far as I know that is not a supported configuration, as the converter needs to run in the context of a specifically-privileged local account and local accounts are not available on a W2K3 DC.